# What is a good software package for topic modelling using HDP (Hierarchical Dirichlet Process)?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I was using the HDP ([Hierarchical Dirichlet Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Dirichlet_process)) package from [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) topic modelling software. HDP is supposed to determine the number of topics on its own from the data.
 However, the gensim HDP implementation expects user to provide the number of topics in advance:

```
hdpmodel.HdpModel(self, corpus, id2word,T=150)
```

The documentation defines T as top level truncation level. But this 'T' actually determines the number of topics generated as output.

I am looking for an implementation of HDP which can detect the number of topics on its own.

Comment: Have you looked at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html#dpgmm-classifier-infinite-gaussian-mixtures to see if it suits your needs?